# How do I include resources in an Android Library?

Tags: android

I have an Android project. In it I include an Android library. The library contains an Activity that references resources (also contained within the library).

In my host project I extend the libraries activity. The code compiles, but when I run it I get a runtime exception stating that the extended project cannot find a layout resource:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mylibrary.R$layout
```

My question is, how can I fix my library so that the referenced resources are included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My project wasn't actually including the libraries, as my source control had set the project.properties file to read-only. Eclipse failed silently.

Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that R.java is generated in your library project under gen folder

Check here for more details,
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html
#Library Project